# jstl: If class="active", fill a string with Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

I am inside a ul list that takes values from a xml file like this.

```
<ul class="nav-justified pickLanguage">
    <x:forEach select="$con/index/language-sigla" var="item">
        <li>
            <a id="<x:out select="$item"/>" href="#" onClick="takeId(this.id)" class="">
                    <x:out select="$item"/>
            </a>                            
        </li>
    </x:forEach>
</ul>
```

The function "takeId" gives  class="active" if I click on the link.
No, I want to say: if class==active, put the value of the id, into a string that I will call String idName
but I don't know how to do this. Could anyone help me?

Comment: what do you mean, please be specific and more clear

Comment: What I did is a list; when I click on an item of the list, the class of that item turns into "active".
What I want is that, if the class is active, the string is equal of the item's id.

Example:
List:
<li><a class="" id="Item_1">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a class="" id="Item_2">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a class="" id="Item_3">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a class="" id="Item_4">Item 4</a></li>

String idName = .....

Now, I click on Item 3. That's means that its class turns into active. I want 
String idName = "Item_3"

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean by String idName, if you refer it to as javascript variable then you can do it like following

```
<script>
vat idName = "";

function takeId(id){
 $('#'+id).addClass('active');
 idName = "id";
}

</script
```

In case your String idName is a server level variable then you cannot do this using javascript.

Comment: I know this, what I want is that the string is printed inside my web page.

In other words, if I click on Item 2 that has id="Item_2", on the web page will appear an information (NOT ON POPUP BUT ON PAGE!) that says "The item you clicked has id="Item_2" ",

I was thinking about this using <c:out value="${idName}" escapeXml="false"/> but I don't really know how to catch idName